# ALAsset getting HDR image or not

Tags: objective-c, ios, image, image-processing

tried to do a search but didn’t see this question anywhere.  Is there a property in ALAsset that lets me know whether a specific image is HDR or not? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not directly, but you can get the photo metadata from the ALAsset and check for the presence of the "CustomRendered" key. I believe that it's set to a value higher than 1 for HDR images by the iPhone camera. Just tested and got one with a value of 3 but I've heard of people getting different values so your mileage may vary.